# Cron log performance info

Tags: cron

Hi i am doing a cron job

> 0 20  * * * curl http://server/import.php >> ~/cronlog/import`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`.html 2>&1

and i am having the folloing speed log everywhere in the log file how can i change it to show at the end of the file or not show.

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
--:--:--     0   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0 Text html 

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03
--:--:--     0   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0
--:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0 Text html    0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--     0   0     0    0     0  0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:07 --:--:--     0   0     0    0  0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:08 --:--:--     0   0     0  0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--     0
```

Answer (score 1):

You should execute your script on this way:

```
0 20 * * * curl -s http://server/import.php >> ~/cronlog/import`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`.html 2>&1
```

This will suppress the output of progress bar in STDOUT/STDERR